# How can I grab or extrude an edge at an existing, arbitrary angle?

Tags: modeling, vertices, extrude

Let's say I have a little tent shape, like this:

[image: tent shape]

I've decided I want the bottom segment to follow the diagonal angle of the top segment instead of being vertical. I could grab the bottom four vertices and move them along the X-axis like so:

[image: bottom four vertices selected]
[image: bottom four vertices dragged along x-axis]

I could also delete these vertices, and select those above them then grab or extrude along the angle. The problem is, I don't know how to do that! How can I lock the grab/extrusion to continue on along the angle of the tent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a way to do it with custom orientation and scale on the 3D cursor, but it's a bit tedious, so the simplest way to get the same thing it is to delete the bottom vertices, and slide the face with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> to extend. You can snap on the grid (with the *Absolute Grid Snap* option enabled):

[image]

Then at the end add the edge loop where it is supposed to be

Or as pointed out by Marty Fouts, choose *Normal* orientation in the *Transform Orientations* panel and move along the good axis.

Or create a custom orientation on the face (the "+" button in the *Transform Orientations* panel) and extrude along the right axis, this way you keep the edge where it originally is:

[image]

Comment: One nice thing I've noticed.. GG snaps now. I'm sure it used to take no notice of snapping?

Comment: yes it's new since 2.8 or 2.9

Comment: You're right I'm going to specify that

Comment: A sometimes better way is to change the space to Normal and then extrude along the Z axis.

Comment: Oh yes you're right, I didn't realize it was possible. Edit: Actually it doesn't work for an extrusion as it will loose the face axis, so it works like a slide.

Comment: I've chosen this as the anwer---thank you for your help!

Comment: you're welcome, there may be another way but it doesn't come to my mind for the moment  ;)